# How to execute laravel artisan commands in linux server

Tags: php, linux, laravel, laravel-artisan

I have uploaded my project on a Linux server, but I don't know how to execute Laravel commands on the server.

Commands:

```
php artisan migrate
php artisan migrate:rollback
php artisan migrate:reset
php artisan migrate:refresh
php artisan db:seed
```

Comment: From your server's terminal (through a protocol like SSH) navigate to your Laravel project's root directory and simply run the commands from there.

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: You could try doing 'ls' and see if artisan is listed in the directory you are in. As stated above, this should be in the laravel project's root directory

Comment: @LiamHammett without having to ssh, do you know how to run a shell script that executes an artisan command? A reusable script type of deal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the lemp stack is installed along with composer. Run `composer install` Then the command should be available.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-laravel-with-an-nginx-web-server-on-ubuntu-14-04